# What can JavaScript learn from Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby

The ECMAScript working group has started working on the next edition of the language. What can they learn from Ruby?

Comment: What's JavaScript? Isn't that the VM that JQeury runs on?

Comment: Vague question, and I'm not sure why it's centered on Ruby. (JavaScript could learn from lots of languages, why specifically Ruby?)

Comment: kind of a nonsensical question imho. Why should they learn anything from Ruby? Why not from C#? or SQL? The two languages are in entirely different problem domains.

Comment: "The two languages are in entirely different problem domains." I don't quite get this.

Comment: How about Python? I'd rather learn from Python if I have a choice. :-)

Comment: Everybody has their own interests. People interested in Javascript in relation to other languages are of course free to ask about those.

Comment: @Nosredna: JavaScript has been learning from Python for a while now, with generators, iterators, array comprehensions and generator expressions, and assignment unpacking added as of JavaScript 1.8.

Comment: @Miles, yes, but that's not ECMAScript, is JavaScript. I mean, there's nothing standard.

Comment: @Ionut G. Stan: Yes.  Though the failed ECMAScript 4 draft did incorporate some of those features.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually a much more challenging question than it appears at first.

The main reason for this is that it's been shown to be very difficult to force browser vendors, by way of specification, to implement the pet or favourite features of language enthusiasts, users, other vendors, or academics without very good justifications. This is how we ended up with the ES4 spec pretty much dead on the table, which yielded a much less ambitious (though still pretty awesome) ES Harmony. A language like JavaScript which has such insanely tricky political deployment and implementation issues is simply unable to be the type of awesome experimental playground that Ruby has been for much of its lifetime. Anyone who has followed es-discuss (the ECMAScript language development mailing list) has probably noticed by now that it takes many many months of debate and experimentation to merely articulate and agree upon common language features like, in recent memory, operator overloading, or short form lambda notation.

Perhaps it may be too much to ask of any working group to nail a spec that will target every device on the planet? On the surface it would appear that it's a very narrow band of lessons, even the social ones, that can be easily transferred from Ruby to the JavaScript.

To that end, and to ease the burden of Brendan Eich and his group:

One of the most urgently useful "lessons" to bring to the language from a perspective inspired by Ruby (or LISP) would be **language malleability**. The ability to introduce new features, syntax hacks and domain-specific languages not originating from a inner cabal of spec writers would be incredibly valuable. Allow the language to be a good place for modular extensions to the language to be made, and for those extensions to be **self-hosted**, so as to minimize fragmentation risks and to allow those changes to permeate and be mashed up, etc.

Such malleability would allow the **community** at large to apply lessons from all sorts of directions and allow the Internet to decide over time which lessons are worthwhile from which language, etc. We've already got a high rate of iteration and evolution happening at the other ends of this sandwich, i.e. in browsers themselves (eg: HTML5), and in js libraries. If that was able to happen more intimately at the language level, we could see some very interesting things happen very quickly.

**[addendum/edit]:**

The language has to be able to morph significantly because a small group of people is simply incapable of anticipating all the things it'll ever be used for. A theme that comes up on es-discuss often is that underlying current of designing "a language for the next 10-15 years". IMHO, this is an incredibly unrealistic goal. If you don't build it, the system **will** evolve an alternative long before spec's intended lifetime. With the immense speedup in javascript engine/JIT technology of late, we're already seeing the early signs of this happening in the form of new languages being written **on top of JavaScript** or being cross-compiled on the fly into JavaScript. Yep, even Ruby: http://hotruby.yukoba.jp/

Comment: HotRuby was around before V8 and JIT JavaScript. But you make a good point. There's nothing wrong with JS being the assembly language of the web, though. It's good that it's getting fast enough to be that.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess what I'm trying to say is that there are invisible trends that are manifesting themselves in various ways, not necessarily in any coordinated fashion or order :) I agree on the assembly language part. Speeds *are* getting rather crazy.

Answer (score 5):

Embrace function programming, don't try to bury it in static language constructs

Answer (score 4):

Having a name that sounds like a gemstone is much better than a name that sounds like a skin disease.

But don't name your new language after today's hottest thing (that's how we all got into this "Java"script mess in the first place....)

Comment: what a flip response! I'm glad much more serious replies have shown up.

Comment: But still true. How many times do we see questions tagged "Java" when they are talking about ECMAscript?

Answer (score 4):

build a standard library around the heavy use of closures, both for collection iteration and for the acquire resource/yield resource/dispose of resource pattern. that's one of ruby's biggest wins, imo. of course, part of what enables this is the brilliant decision to give every method one 'free' closure parameter, with syntactic support, so it's probably not going to look as nice in javascript. the techniques are still useful, though.

Comment: +1 for explaining this part of ruby in a way that can actually be understood, instead of saying "blocks are cool".

Answer (score -2):

I can't see to much that it could learn from Ruby. The standards group has already given the language a mean to do resend messages, or messages to the protoype. The method_missing functionality might be cool to implement, but it isn't as necessary as better refelction facilities.